# AzureFunction created with python, HTTP request length is limited to 100MB

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

We are using AzureFunction created with python, in which we are facing an issue "Request body too large." While calling an API with multipart file upload around 200MB.

While we gone through some support link given below, we noticed HTTP request length is limited to 100MB.

We also tried editing the web.config through ssh, but still we are facing the same issue, also after restart functionapp service web.config file gets resetted to 100MB restriction.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp

Kindly provide some workaround to resolve this "Request body too large." issue.

Answer (score 0):

On this [ticket](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1063#issuecomment-465665396) that originally discussed increasing size to 100 MB, seems like this work around was suggested for sizes greater than the max:

> **paulbatum** commented on Dec 14, 2018 @two2tee You're not totally off.
>
> In the case of functions you can't configure this (thats what this
> issue tracks). Our general recommendation is to switch to a flow where
> large files are uploaded to blob storage which are then processed by
> your functions.

There is also this [open item](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5854) on allowing content body over 100MB that you might want to follow.